# Do associated futures complete on closing of channel?

Tags: java, asynchronous, network-programming, netty, future

If I create a future by `Channels.future(Channel)`, is it automatically completed (to failure?) when the channel is closed? (Netty 3.10.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not... Notification is up to you.